# Xcode 13 and Cocoapods, how to disable assertions?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, assertion

I want to disable assertions to avoid asserts failures from third part libraries installed with Cocoapods also for the debug phase, not only release.
To reach this goal I've disabled Enable Foundation Assertions from my **project section** as showed in this image:

[image]

and for my target section:

[image]

For Pods I've changed my **Podfile** adding to the bottom part before the end statement this code:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS'] = 'NO'
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

When I open my project workspace on Xcode , I see that also Pods project section and all target section have the same parameter turned to NO for both debug and release.

Now I'm in DEBUG mode with my simulator, when I launch my app assertions still works and my app still stops to assertion failure:

```
assert(false,"warning, change your file name with this...")
```

Are there any other parameters to turn off that I have forgotten?

P.S.:
Xcode 13 final version (13A233)
Cocoapods v1.11.2

Comment: You would need to audit all your third party deps extremely carefully because continuing after an assert fail is really undefined behaviour territory - if you're doing that, might as well fork them and remove the asserts?

Comment: @Shadowrun Unfortunately the assertions are inside the third party library code, not mine.